# displaying number of names in a new line in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, java.util.scanner

Trying to create a program which takes an input of names and also returns the next name from the inputted names, starting at a given position. Then writes all the names to the console each on a new line. was able to get the program to count names but not sure how to display an array of names in the new line as well as the recent name entered. this is what I've done so far:

```
public class stringnames {
    public static String[] countNames (String names) {

     @SuppressWarnings("resource")
     Scanner names1 =new Scanner(System.in);
     String read= names1.nextLine();
     String numPeople[]=read.trim().split(" ");
     System.out.println("The Number of names inputted is:  "+ numPeople.length);
     return numPeople;
}

public static void main(String[ ] args){

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of names you want(make sure you make space for each name):\n");
    countNames(null);
}

public static void getname(){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have stored the names in the variable `String numPeople[]`, moreover you return it.

The only left to do is to get the array, loop it and print it out on the new line.

```
String[] names = countNames(null);
for (String n : names){
     System.out.println(n);
}
```

---

However I recommend you to add the names to `List`.

```
public static List<String> getNames() {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     String line = sc.nextLine();
     String numPeople[]=line.trim().split(" ");
     sc.close();
     return Arrays.asList(numPeople);
}   

public static void main(String[ ] args){

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of names you want(make sure you make space for each name):\n");
    List<String> names = getNames();
    System.out.println("The Number of names inputted is:  " + names.size());
    System.out.println("Names:");
    for (String n : names) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[ ] args){

    System.out.println("Enter the amount of names you want(make sure you make space for each name):\n");

    String[] names = countNames();

    for(String name : names){
       System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Comment: It will not even compile. There is no `string` and `foreach` in Java.

Comment: how do i also display a specific name in the index as well from the array?